# Não é possível converter Implicitamente

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> Não é possível converter de "TClient" para "EasySistema.Models.ApplicationClient"

```
public class ClientManager<TClient> 
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ClientManager(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public virtual async Task CreateClientAsync(TClient client)
    {
        var result = await _context.Clientes.Add(client);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Task.FromResult(result);

    }
}
```

A chamada está sendo feita através de:

```
var result = await _clientManager.CreateClientAsync(client);
```

Essa é a definição de _clientManager:

```
    private readonly ClientManager<ApplicationClient> _clientManager;

    public ClientController (
        ClientManager<ApplicationClient> clientManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole,
ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationRoleClaim, ApplicationUserToken>
{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationClient> Clientes { get; set; }
```

E essa é minha ApplicationClient:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EasySistema.Models
{
public class ApplicationClient
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Tipo Pessoa")]
    public int TipoPessoa { get; set; }
}
```

Poderiam me ajudar por favor, pois não vejo aonde estou errando, e não consigo resolver.

Comment: A sua classe `ClientManager` está à espera de uma classe do tipo `TClient` e não `ApplicationClient`, por isso, ao fazer `private readonly ClientManager<ApplicationClient> _clientManager;` está a provocar o erro. A não ser que a classe `ApplicationClient` herde da `TClient`, aí já é diferente.

Comment: Eu acredito que será ao contrario ele esta recebendo TClient mas espera receber EasySistema.Models.ApplicationClient não é ? por isso fiz `private readonly ClientManager<ApplicationClient> _clientManager;` para que pudesse passar  "EasySistema.Models.ApplicationClient".

Comment: Ou que esteja falando de generics on `TClient` fosse simplesmente `T` o que não parece ser pelo restante do contexto

Comment: A sua coleção `ApplicationDbContext.Clientes` é uma coleção com o tipo `ApplicationClient`?

Comment: Pagotti coloquei minha ApplicationDbContext em minha pergunta

Comment: Ò que é a `TClient` e porque você está usando ela?

Comment: A minha ideia era através da TClient passar o parâmetro  `EasySistema.Models.ApplicationClient` através da construção do método `private readonly ClientManager<ApplicationClient> _clientManager;` mas não está funcionando pelo jeito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem o porque do TClient, mas vamos lá:

*_context.Clientes.Add* espera adicionar um item do tipo *ApplicationClient*. E a sua classe de entidade *ApplicationClient* não herda de *TClient*. Assim não é possível converter um tipo em outro implicitamente.

O que você pode fazer é a conversão explícita:

```
public virtual async Task<ApplicationClient> CreateClientAsync(TClient client)    
{

    var result =  await _context.Clientes.AddAsync((client as ApplicationClient));     

    if (result.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return result.Entity;      
}
```

Ou então colocar na assinatura da classe a definição do tipo esperado:

```
public class ClientManager<TClient> where TClient : ApplicationClient
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ClientManager(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
       _context = context;
    }

 public virtual async Task<ApplicationClient> CreateClientAsync(TClient client)    
 {

     var result =  _context.Clientes.Add(client);     

     if (result.State == EntityState.Added)
     {
        _context.SaveChanges();
     }

     return result.Entity;
   }    
}
```

Ou passar o tipo direto como parâmetro no método:

```
public virtual async Task<ApplicationClient> CreateClientAsync(ApplicationClient client)
```